# How do I execute/initialize my class to output my python script?

Tags: python, sql-server

Here is my code:

```
import pyodbc
import logging
import json

class UpdateTables:

    def connect_db(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        with open(r'scriptpath\config_file.json','r') as ts:
            config = json.load(ts)

        self.driver = config['driver']
        self.server = config['server']
        self.database = config['database']

        try:
            conn = pyodbc.connect(
            f'Driver={self.driver};'
            f'Server={self.server};'
            f'Database={self.database};'
            )

            logger.info("Successfully connected to database")

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Unable to connect to database: %s", str(e))

        return conn

    def read_query(self, conn):
        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            read_table_query="""
                SELECT TOP 2 table_name
                FROM information_schema.tables;
                """
            cursor.execute(read_table_query)              

            for tables in cursor.fetchall():
                tab = tables[0]
                write_table_query = f'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM {tab};'
                print(write_table_query)
                print(cursor.fetchall())
                cursor.execute(write_table_query)

        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception(e)

        return cursor
```

Basically I am connecting to SQL Server by reading the credentials in a separate config file, selecting the tables I want to query, and just doing a `SELECT *` on them. When I run my code, it executes without errors but nothing is printed out. I thought the `"Successfully connected to database"` and the output from the `SELECT` statement should appear but it's not. I am not sure what I did wrong, did I not initialize my class/functions properly?

Comment: A class is a description or framework of how data and behavior are related. It doesn't do anything by itself - you need to create an instance of that class (an object) to do work.

Comment: usually you do something like: `f = UpdateTables(); f.read_query(f.connect_db());`  but without the ';'